# Visa refused in Admin Process but passports are in hold

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, applications

we have applied for B1/B2 for my wife and as I'm the sponsorer and I already have a visa , I put my passport also as supporting document. The case has been moved to Admin process and with in 2 days we got a status as "Visa Refused". Now we haven't got our passports back and it has already been a month. How do I get back my passport as I have a trip outside india. Is there any average wait time for getting back our documents?. I don't find it logical as the decision on the visa has already taken and I wonder why our documents are still at the embassy.

Comment: AFAIK, what is known as "administrative processing" is formally considered as refusal under INA 221(g). This refusal is overturned as soon as "administrative processing" is complete.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely not a "vanilla" refusal; rather they suspect you of some type of fraud, and are investigating your person further.

You can call the embassy and ask about it, but don't expect any answer.

Comment: my husband never overstayed and travelled 4 times till date on B1/B2 and what type of fraud could be there ? haha !